# JS Inheritance: calling the parent's function from within the child's function

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

There must be something I don't understand about the JS object model.

From these resources:

- [Prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#prototype_and_Object.getPrototypeOf)
- [Basic OOP in JS- Inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance)
- [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

I have gathered what I think, or thought, was an accurate mental representation of the object model. Here it is:

---

All objects have a property, which the docs refer to as `[[Prototype]]`. `[[Prototype]]` can be thought of as a reference to the object's parent. More accurately:

> The reference to the [parent's] prototype object is copied to the
>   internal `[[Prototype]]` property of the new instance. ([source 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#prototype_and_Object.getPrototypeOf))

You can get access to the `[[Prototype]]` property of the child with `Object.getPrototypeOf(child)` The value returned here will be a reference to the parent's prototype (not its internal `[[Prototype]]` property, but its actual prototype)

`obj.prototype` is different from the object's internal `[[Prototype]]` property. It acts like the blueprints used to make instances of this exact object, while its `[[Prototype]]` property points to the blueprints used to make instances of its parent.

- `Parent.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(child); //true`

To elaborate:

- If you add a function to `child.prototype` the function will be available to `child` and any of it's children.
- If you add a function to `parent.prototype`, which is equivalent to adding a function to `Object.getPrototypeOf(child)`, then the function will be available to `parent` and all of it's children, which includes `child` and all of its `siblings`.

You can use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create a new object with whatever `[[Protoype]]` property you want. So you can use it as a way to implement inheritance. See [source 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance) for an example.

---

With this in mind, I wanted to get a working example of my own going. My plan was to create a parent 'class' and then make a child 'class' that inherited from it.

I wanted the child class to implement a method, which overloaded a method from the parent. The caveat is that I want the child's version of the method to call the parent's version of the method and then do some extra stuff.

Here is what I came up with, see below for the issues associated with it:

```js
var Parent = function() {};

Parent.prototype.myF = function() {
  console.log('derp');
};


function Child() {
  Parent.call(this);
};

//make [[prototype]] of Child be a ref to Parent.prototype
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

//need to explicitly set the constructor
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

Child.prototype.myF = function() {
  Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myF();
  console.log("did I derp??");
};

childInstance = new Child();
childInstance.myF();
```

It appears to be the case that when I attempt to overload `Parent.myF()`, while I am overloading it, I am actually modifying the original function at the same time. This appears to be the case because the logged results are:

```
'derp'
'did I derp??'
'did I derp??'
```

presumably the first occurance of `'did I derp??'` is coming from a modified version of the parent's function, which I *don't* mean to do, then the second version is coming from the child's function.

Can anyone elaborate on why this is happening?

Comment: Extremely well written question.

Comment: Confirming the OP's output in chrome and same as firefox. @Ankit: did you check for the red "2" on the right in the mozilla firefox dev edition? http://prntscr.com/78578d

Comment: There's one error in your understanding. `obj.prototype` isn't a thing. Only functions have a `.prototype` property. Objects have a `.constructor` property. So it's really `obj.constructor.prototype`.

Comment: `[[Prototype]] can be thought of as a reference to the object's parent` - Actually, the prototype of the parent is part of the prototype chain that is checked when a function on the child is invoked. And the prototypes of all ancestors form part of this chain, all the way back to the root `Object`. So if a call to `child.Foo()` doesn't invoke anything on the child instance or the child's prototype, then the interpreter will check `parent.prototype.Foo()`, and if it exists, will invoke that. If it doesn't exist, we will check for `grandParent.prototype.Foo()`, etc...

Comment: @MisterEpic my understanding is that `[[Prototype]]` is the mechanism by which the 'prototype chain' is implemented. -- if you don't find `Foo()` in `Child`, then follow the reference provided by `child`s `[[Prototype]]` property

Comment: The function on the parent's prototype never gets altered in your program.

Comment: @LukeP Prototypal inheritance is all about augmentation. Look at this line: `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);` You've pulled in all the parent prototype's methods by doing so, but then you extend the child's prototype by adding `myF()`. That isn't referencing the parent's prototype, you are extending it.

Comment: @TheWarlock so why is it logged twice?

Comment: What do you think you are doing with this line? `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);` It is logged twice because at least in my debugger Child's prototype ends up as Child.

Comment: @MisterEpic "You've pulled in all the parent prototype's methods by doing so"   --    are you saying that I'm not referencing the parent's prototype, but instead that the child's `[[Prototype]]` contains a *copy* of the parent's prototype?

Comment: @barry-johnson *I think* that I am creating a new object, whose `[[prototype]]` property contains a reference to `Parent.prototype`, thus establishing the child-parent relationship

Comment: You overload prototype functions the same way as you re use Patent constructor: Parent.prototype.myF.call(this)

Comment: @LukeP why did you unaccept my answer?

Comment: @LukeP thank you for explaining. I figured explaining the process of coming to the answer might help debugging similar problems in the future. I'll gladly append your first fiddle, but I'd rather not put in the second one, as `__proto__` has only been standardized in ES6 and with ES6, classes are the cleaner solution (if you want to work with constructors, that is). More on `__proto__`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto
Are you alright with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question, it took a bit of testing and researching to find it out.

### Identifying the strange behaviour

I changed your code a little bit to find out which function is called when:

```
var Parent = function() {};

Parent.prototype.myF = function() {
  console.log('derp');
};


function Child() {
  Parent.call(this);
  this.name = 'Test'; // this is a new test property
};

//make [[prototype]] of Child be a ref to Parent.prototype
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

//need to explicitly set the constructor
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

Child.prototype.myF = function() {
  console.log(this); // here I want to find out the context, because you use it in the next line
  Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myF();
  console.log("did I derp??");
};

childInstance = new Child();
childInstance.myF();
```

You can check out the JSFiddle and try it for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpxq78bs/

The crucial line in your code is this:

```
Child.prototype.myF = function() {
  Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myF(); // this one
  console.log("did I derp??");
};
```

After doing a `console.log(this);` to find out what `this` refers to, I saw that it changes between the first and the second output of `did I derp??`.

I got the following output:

```
Object { name: "Test" }
Object { constructor: Child(), myF: window.onload/Child.prototype.myF() }
"derp"
"did I derp??"
"did I derp??"
```

### Interpreting the Output

Since I added a 'name' property to the `Child` constructor, it would only be around if I am looking at an instance of `Child`, not at its `.prototype`.

So the first line of the Output means that the current `this` context is indeed the `childInstance`. **But the second one is neither the `childInstance`, nor the `Parent.prototype`**:

1. Call (`myF` of `childInstance`): `this` refers to the `childInstance`. `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myF();` then looks for the `[[Prototype]]` of the `childInstance`, **which is the `Child.prototype`, not the `Parent.prototype`**.
   Output: 'did I derp??'
2. Call **(`myF` of `Child.prototype`)**: `this` refers to the `Child.prototype`, which is the `childInstances` [[Prototype]] Property. So the second call of `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myF();` finally returns the `Parent.prototype` (sort of). Output: 'did I derp??'
3. Call (`myF` of `Parent.prototype` instance created by `Object.create`): Finally, the `myF` on the parent is called. Output: 'derp'

Since your `console.log("did I derp??")` comes after the `myF` function call, *the output is in reverse order.* The following graphic illustrates how the code is traversed:

[image]

So your assumption about what `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myF();` refers to, was wrong.

### Solution in ES5

By @LukeP:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lpxq78bs/28/

### Alternative Solution in ES6

To avoid this confusion, and since you are working with a classical inheritance pattern, you could have a look at [ES6 Classes](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html). The following would be a rough example of what you are trying to do:

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
      
    }
    
    myF() {
        console.log('derp');
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    myF() {
        super.myF();
        console.log("did I derp??");
    }
}

var childInstance = new Child();
childInstance.myF();
```

I hope this helps in understanding what happens.

Comment: Why the output is always **did i derp** in all your cases

Comment: so the output sequence is...`did I derp?? - did I derp?? - derp` or the reverse? According to this answer it looks like this.. but the reverse is being logged. Can you please explain how?

Comment: @The Warlock I just added a graphic that I hope makes it clearer. Since the `console.log` comes after the functions calls, the last function displays its `console.log('derp')` first.

Comment: Awesome! I kinda figured that out after reading your answer again but the graphic really helps!

Comment: @nils I apologize, but I made a mistake in my jsFiddle, can you update the ES5 solution link to: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpxq78bs/28/     -- when calling the super function, as HMR pointed out in the comments, you need to override the default value of 'this' in order to get access to the instance variables.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is working as expected , the output you are getting is because of `Object.getPrototypeOf` and can be explained by

**Step 1** : When you cal `childInstance.myF();` then it goes to below code where `this` refers to childInstance itself

```
Child.prototype.myF = function() {
  Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myF();
  console.log("did I derp??");
};
```

then `Object.getPrototypeOf` returns `childInstance.[[Prototype]]` which is `Child.prototype` and again call `myF` method(leaving second line to printed later after the execution of the method) but next time `this` will reference to `childInstance.[[Prototype]]`.

**Step 2** : In this call `this` points to `childInstance.[[Prototype]]`( or `Child.prototype` object itself)

```
Child.prototype.myF = function() {
  Object.getPrototypeOf(this).myF();
  console.log("did I derp??");
};
```

Now `Object.getPrototypeOf` returns `childInstance.[[Prototype]].[[Prototype]]`( which is `Child.prototype.[[Prototype]]`) which is `Parent.prototype` and again call myF method but this time myF method will print **derp** because myF method of `Parent.prototype` is being called. After that, second line will print **did i derp**.

**Step 3** : Then the function comes back to step 1 to execute second line which again prints **did i derp**

Comment: Great explanation, there is only a small error: In Step 2, `this` points to `Child.prototype` or `childInstance.[[Prototype]]`, which are a reference to the same thing. `Child.[[Prototype]]` is just empty at this point. You can look at it in the browser: `Object.getPrototypeOf(Child);`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to work with inheritance in ES5 I have made a wrapper that makes it easy to extend and call parent methods. No frameworks required.

fiddle to working code here: https://jsfiddle.net/wcrwLmrk/13/

Here is how the code works:

```
/* extend the base class to the new parent class and pass 
an object with the new properties and methods */
var ParentClass = Class.extend(  
{ 
    // reset the constructor to the correct constructor
    constructor: function() 
    { 

    },

    callName: function(arg)
    { 
        console.log('parent ' + arg); 
    }
}); 

/* extend the parent class to the new child class and pass 
an object with the new properties and methods */
var ChildClass = ParentClass.extend(  
{ 
    // reset the constructor to the correct constructor
    constructor: function() 
    { 
        ParentClass.call(this); 
    },

    callName: function(arg)
    { 
        // child method code
        console.log('child ' + arg);

        /* call parent method by passing the method name and any params */ 
        this.super('callName', arg); 
    }
});
```

Now we can create a new child class that will 
call the super class method:

```
var child = new ChildClass(); 
child.callName('name');
```

Here is the base class that needs to be included in the project:

```
var Class = function() 
{ 

}; 

Class.prototype =  
{ 
    constructor: Class, 

    /* this is an alias for callParent. this will 
    allow child classes to call super methods. 
    @param (string) method name 
    @param [(mixed)] addasmany args as the super 
    method needs 
    @return (mixed) the super method return value */
    super: function()
    { 
        var parent = this.parent; 
        if(parent)
        { 
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments), 

            // this will remove the first arg as the method
            method = args.shift(); 
            if(method)
            { 
                var func = parent[method]; 
                if(typeof func === 'function')
                { 
                    return func.apply(this, args);
                } 
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
}; 

/* this will return a new object and extend it if an object it supplied. 
@param [(object)] object = the extending object 
@return (object) this will return a new object with the 
inherited object */ 
var createObject = function(object) 
{ 
    if(!Object.create) 
    { 
        var obj = function(){}; 
        obj.prototype = object;
        return new obj(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return Object.create(object); 
    } 
}; 

/* this will extend an object and return the extedned 
object or false.  
@param (object) sourceObj = the original object 
@param (object) targetObj = the target object */ 
var extendObject = function(sourceObj, targetObj) 
{ 
    if(typeof sourceObj !== 'undefined' && typeof targetObj !== 'undefined') 
    { 
        for(var property in sourceObj) 
        { 
            if(sourceObj.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof targetObj[property] === 'undefined') 
            { 
                targetObj[property] = sourceObj[property]; 
            } 
        } 

        return targetObj; 
    } 
    return false; 
}; 

var extendClass = function(sourceClass, targetClass) 
{ 
    /* if we are using a class constructor function 
    we want to get the class prototype object */  
    var source = (typeof sourceClass === 'function')? sourceClass.prototype : sourceClass, 
    target = (typeof targetClass === 'function')? targetClass.prototype : targetClass;

    if(typeof source === 'object' && typeof target === 'object') 
    { 
        /* we want to create a new object and add the source 
        prototype to the new object */ 
        var obj = createObject(source); 

        /* we need to add any settings from the source that 
        are not on the prototype */ 
        extendObject(source, obj); 

        /* we want to add any additional properties from the 
        target class to the new object */ 
        for(var prop in target) 
        { 
            obj[prop] = target[prop]; 
        } 

        return obj; 
    } 
    return false; 
}; 

/* this will allow the classes to be extened. 
@param (object) child = the child object to extend 
@return (mixed) the new child prototype or false */ 
Class.extend = function(child)
{  
    if(!child)
    { 
        return false; 
    } 

    var parent = this.prototype; 

    /* the child constructor must be set to set 
    the parent static methods on the child */ 
    var constructor = child && child.constructor? child.constructor : false; 
    if(child.hasOwnProperty('constructor') === false)
    { 
        constructor = function()
        {
            var args = arguments; 
            parent.constructor.apply(this, args); 
        }; 
    }

    constructor.prototype = extendClass(parent, child); 
    constructor.prototype.parent = parent;

    /* this will add the static methods from the parent to 
    the child constructor. */ 
    extendObject(this, constructor); 
    return constructor; 
};
```